# Python write in mkstemp() file

Tags: python, mkstemp

I am creating a tmp file by using :

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
```

I am trying to write in this file :

```
tmp_file = mkstemp()
file = open(tmp_file, 'w')
file.write('TEST\n')
```

Indeed I close the file and do it proper but when I try to cat the tmp file, it stills empty..It looks basic but I don't know why it doesn't work, any explanations ?

Comment: Yes I do it. file.close(), I even tried to get the fd and close it using os.close(fd)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`mkstemp()` returns a tuple with a file descriptor and a path. I think the issue is that you're writing to the wrong path. (You're writing to a path like `'(5, "/some/path")'`.) Your code should look something like this:

```
from tempfile import mkstemp

fd, path = mkstemp()

# use a context manager to open the file at that path and close it again
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write('TEST\n')

# close the file descriptor
os.close(fd)
```

Comment: Well, I tried to use both, when I do path = mkstemp(), it returns only the path of the file. And it stills create the file at the right path, that's why I think it's not the problem.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner I don't see how that could be. If you do `path = mkstemp(); print(path)`, what's the output? I'm pretty sure it has to be a tuple.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner What version of Python are you using? (Perhaps older versions have a different behavior.)

Comment: My mistake, I did fd, temp_file = mkstemp()  print '\n' + temp_file, I had not even noticed it. So yes you're right it returns a tuple, sorry for the waste of time :( @smarx

Comment: I tried to add a comment but it would not be formatted properly. Therefore I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 38):

The answer by smarx opens the file by specifying `path`. It is, however, easier to specify `fd` instead. In that case the context manager closes the file descriptor automatically:

```
import os
from tempfile import mkstemp

fd, path = mkstemp()

# use a context manager to open (and close) file descriptor fd (which points to path)
with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as f:
    f.write('TEST\n')

# This causes the file descriptor to be closed automatically
```

Answer (score 8):

This example opens the Python file descriptor with [`os.fdopen`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fdopen) to write cool stuff, then close it (at the end of the `with` context block). Other non-Python processes can use the file. And at the end, the file is deleted.

```
import os
from tempfile import mkstemp

fd, path = mkstemp(text=True)

with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('cool stuff\n')

# Do something else with the file, e.g.
# os.system('cat ' + path)

# Delete the file
os.remove(path)
```

Comment: Python3.11(I didn't test all versions) doesn't delete it. I recommend `os.remove(path)`. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636018/python-difference-between-os-remove-and-os-unlink-and-which-one-to-use#comment105879589_42636082)

Comment: I think this code has an error.  Shouldn't you say `mkstemp(text=True)`?  the default will return a file descriptor in BINARY mode, but apparently you want TEXT mode

Answer (score 3):

mkstemp returns (fd, name) where fd is an os-level file descriptor ready for writing in binary mode; so all you need is to use `os.write(fd, 'TEST\n')`, and then `os.close(fd)`.

No need to re-open the file using either `open` or `os.fdopen`.

```
jcomeau@bendergift:~$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> from tempfile import mkstemp
>>> fd, name = mkstemp()
>>> os.write(fd, 'TEST\n')
5
>>> print(name)
/tmp/tmpfUDArK
>>> os.close(fd)
>>> 
jcomeau@bendergift:~$ cat /tmp/tmpfUDArK 
TEST
```

In command-line testing, of course, there is no need to use `os.close`, since the file is closed on exit anyway. But that is bad programming practice.

Comment: `os.write()` is a binary interface, while `os.fdopen()` allows to open in text mode, so you get correct new lines for your system. It also allows to specify `encoding` so writes will encode strings as desired.

Comment: @wonder.mice I think that `os.write` can be either text or binary.  if you open the descriptor using `mkstemp(text=True)` then it will be text mode.