# How to permanently delete a file in python 3 and higher?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to permanently delete a file i have created with my python code.

I know the os.remove() etc but can't find anything specific to delete a file permanently.(Don't want to fill Trash with unused files)

Comment: Have you checked whether or not os.remove() actually does send things to the Trash?

Comment: I don't know why os.remove() was sending files to Trash/Recycle Bin earlier, but it seems to be working as expected now .. Thanks for the answers !!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`os.remove` is already what you're looking for. It doesn't send things to Trash. It just deletes them.

Comment: Which python module send file to trash? Trash means Recycle Bin?

Comment: @py_saad: I don't think Python comes with any dedicated utility to do that. As for what Trash is, the questioner is probably on OS X or some similar system where the Recycle Bin equivalent is called Trash, or maybe they're on Windows and just using the wrong name.

Comment: If you want to send something to the Recycle Bin or other equivalent location, you'd probably have to explicitly move the file to whatever hidden folder is used to store Recycle Bin contents (or Recycle-Bin-equivalent contents).

Answer (score 8):

Basically both `os.remove()` and `os.unlink()` are same. Both these commands removes the files permanently. You can use either of them to perform the desired operation.

If you just want to delete a single file, you can use the below code.

```
os.unlink(filename)
```

You can use the below code to remove multiple files using extension type.

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        os.unlink(filename)
```

[Source](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter9/)

You can read more about the difference between `os.remove()` and `os.unlink` below.

[os.**remove**(*path*):](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.remove)

> Remove (delete) the file *path*. If *path* is a directory,
>   [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) is raised; see [rmdir()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.rmdir) below to remove a directory. **This is
>   identical to the [unlink()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.unlink) function** documented below. On Windows,
>   attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception to be
>   raised; on Unix, the directory entry is removed but the storage
>   allocated to the file is not made available until the original file is
>   no longer in use.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.

[os.**unlink**(*path*):](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.unlink)

> Remove (delete) the file *path*. **This is the same function as [remove()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.remove);**
>   the [unlink()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.unlink) name is its traditional Unix name.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636082/3091398)

Comment: `os.unlink` is just a synonym for `os.remove`.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can try the os.system() function. Just include Linux commands between the brackets and the command will be executed.

Example: `os.system('rm xxx')` will remove the file named xxx under your working path.

By default, files removed by the `rm` command is not recoverable (unless you have manually set it previously) and you needn't worry about the disk space problem.

Hope it helps!

Comment: If for whatever reason you use this approach, absolutely NEVER allow user input to be piped into this call, e.g. `os.system(f'rm {some_user_input}')`. This is every hacker's dream.