# Python os.remove()

Tags: python, operating-system

I have a more general question about the `os.remove()` -function.
When I use it to delete a file, does Python delete it entirely from the computer or does Python move it to another folder similar to the trash on mac?

Answer (score 0):

`os.remove()` doesn't send things to Trash. It just deletes them.

You can check it yourself very easily:

```
import os

file = 'file.txt'
location = "/home/User/Documents"
path = os.path.join(location, file)
os.remove(path)
print("%s has been removed successfully" % file)
```

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: I checked it by writing eight lines of code

Answer (score 0):

`os.remove` doesn't send things to Trash. It just deletes them.

Here you go for `os.remove` docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

Also i notice similar post on stackoverflow: [How to permanently delete a file in python 3 and higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130303/how-to-permanently-delete-a-file-in-python-3-and-higher)

Comment: How do you know that? That doc doesn't say what "delete" means. If I for example "delete" a file in Windows File Explorer by right-clicking it and clicking "Delete", it *does* go to the Recycle Bin.

Comment: Theire is alreay accepted answer, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130303/how-to-permanently-delete-a-file-in-python-3-and-higher